# invalid hook exception in fetch

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am currently coding in react and I need to get some data from my API. I want to store the received data using hooks. However, when I call the hook "setLoading(false)" which is used to replace the temporary spinner with the actual data I get an "invalid hook exception".

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Spin } from 'antd';
import { SwitchTable } from '../components/SwitchTable';

export function Output() {
  const [fetchFailed, setFetchFailed] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [daten, setDaten] = useState<switchObj[]>();
  const [count, setCount] = useState(10);

 React.useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    fetch('services/Results')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log('fetch returned ok');
        setDaten(data);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        setLoading(false);
        setFetchFailed(e.toString);
      });
  }, []);

 return loading ? (
    <Spin size='large'></Spin>
  ) : (
    <div>
      <p>heyo</p>
      <SwitchTable key={'helo'} switch={daten} /> // not the problem (tested by removing the component and the error still occured but didnt when I removed the useEffect)
    </div>
  );
}

interface switchObj {
  name: string;
  interfaces: interfaceObj[];
}

interface mismatchObj {
  property: string;
  expected: string;
  received: string;
}
interface missingObj {
  property: string;
}

interface interfaceObj {
  portName: string;
  missingValues: missingObj[];
  wrongValues: mismatchObj[];
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
react.development.js:1476 Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    at resolveDispatcher (react.development.js:1476)
    at Object.useContext (react.development.js:1484)
    at useTheme (useTheme.js:4)
    at useStyles (makeStyles.js:222)
    at WithStyles (withStyles.js:55)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14803)
    at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:16816)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18645)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:292)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23203)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22154)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22130)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:21756)
    at react-dom.development.js:11089
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:653)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11039)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:11084)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js:11072)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21199)
    at dispatchAction (react-dom.development.js:15660)
    at req (Output.tsx:29)
```

** the setFetchFailed hook doesnt get executed since the fetch itself works, I received the desired data (checked by printing statement before the hook call)
Does anyone know what I could do or if that isnt possible how I could display the loading component while the fetch is loading?

Comment: Did `setFetchFailed(e.toString);` gets executed? What is the content of `e` in catch exception?

Comment: Is the whole error message saying only "invalid hook exception"?

Comment: Is your hook outside of function component or inside?

Comment: Please include the exact error message along with any context required to understand it. It's not clear where the `useEffect` is called, for example.

Comment: @Isaac no it doesnt get executed sincce the fetch itself works

Comment: @Srivastava its inside

Comment: @Dave Newton useEffect is the first method called after the const initializations

Comment: Your useEffect seems to be fine, but it's difficult to understand with this piece of code alone. You might be doing something incorrect as given in the error messages. Please post your complete component code.

Comment: @this.srivastava I added the code but there is only the return statement.  The problem is, that the rules of hooks ( https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html ) clearly states, that one is not allowed to call hooks inside functions inside the useEffect(), callBack() etc. . However, all solutions I found violated that rule and I dont know how that is possible and I also cant find another solution

Comment: i also tried it with a temporary  variable and setting the hooks later outside the async fetch function but since we cant make useEffect async (because it uses the callback hook, but somehow i saw tutorials do that anyway, no clue how that worked) the async function is queued last and the setHook () is executed before the data is fetched and the initialization value is set

Comment: Please post all of your component, we can't debug if you only show 10% of the project. I think you're misleading what's calling a hook is, you can call setState (return of useState) inside useEffect and there will be no problem, what you can't do is calling useState inside useEffect/useCallback/function inside your function component.

Comment: @Nicolas Menettrier oh wait I reread the line, your actually right it says "Do not call Hooks inside functions passed to useMemo, useReducer, or useEffect." so this is only counts for calling the component and not setting?  Thank you, I think I have been tracing the wrong path. About the code: You are right sorry, I`ll post the whole class, but there really isnt much more. I only have 3 tsx classes and the other two are tested, so i know they are not the problem (I ran them seperatly and they displayed withouth any error they should not be the problem I think)

Comment: I think that specifically the setLoading(false) hook might be the problem

Comment: setLoading(false) is not the hook call, it's the call of the return value of your hook call (useState), setLoading(false) inside a useEffect will never break the rules of hook. I can saw inside the log that they mention call to useThemes and useStyles, do you use it in SwitchTable ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, it was something completely different. The error wasnt with the hooks but with the "antd" (ant-ui) Spin component. The "invalid hook error" occurred at the setLoading() because the hook was used to display an antd component. The antd-ui had a copied version of react in it which caused the error.
I deleted the node_modules folder in ClientApp and also the package.json-lock then I changed the version of react (because antd doesnt support 17.0.1 or smth apparrently) and then it worked. Thanks to everyone for your help!